# What's the advantage of "a,b,c".split(",") over ["a","b","c"]?

Tags: javascript

I've seen this in a couple of places, most notably the `plugins.js` file of [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/), and I'm not sure why.

What's the motivation behind using something like

```
var d = "header,nav,footer".split(",");
```

instead of

```
var d = ["header", "nav", "footer"];
```

?

Comment: It's faster to type, and there's no worrying about mismatched quotes

Comment: Easier to edit. Is it worth it? Meh.

Comment: You say tomato, I say tomato.

Comment: @Brian Roach: You say `"tomato"`, I say `"t" + "o" + "m" + "a" + "t" + "o"`.

Comment: @Asaph: You say `"tomato"`, I say `[ "t", "o", "m", "a", "t", "o" ].join('')`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Under the inexorable pressure of [Moore's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law), it's important to find ways for software to consume more CPU cycles to do the same work. Your particular case (using `split` instead of writing out what you mean in the first place) is an example of "micro-deoptimization".

While there are much more efficient ways to gain inefficiency (code generation templates, preprocessors, and similar tools), it's important for programmers to have a large repertoire of such tricks at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Often people prefer being able to write stuff inside a single string instead of having to write separate strings with quotes etc.

However - when possible - it's usually nicer to do it with space instead of comma since in many languages the `split()` function will use them as a default delimiter if no arguments are specified.

But all in all - it's just a matter of what the developer prefers to write. It's certainly not faster but the difference does not matter at all (you are not going to call this a billion time anyway, *are you*?)

Comment: I'm not calling it at all, I was wondering why I've seen it three times this month, and using different delimiters like pipes and commas, when - as you say - the default is a space. Thought maybe I was missing something.

Comment: Smells like different developers - unless somebody wants to be able to use whatever he just didn't use as a delimiter in one of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the result of an incomplete refactoring: Maybe the string originally came from a config file (or there are plans to split it out into a config file), or from user input. In that case the splitting from a string would be natural.

Or it might even to be to match the style from another section which does use this style of input. Maybe like this:

```
function get_sections()
{
   if has_config()
   {
      return get_config("sections").split(",");
   }
   return "header,nav,footer".split(",");
}
```

A third option might be to make translation easier.

Not that I'd use it in either of those cases, but it might make sense to some developers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage. In fact, it might be slightly less efficient (I haven't checked) do to the invocation of a method on the string, but probably not by much.

This is just a personal preference. Also, people tend to really get a high using string.split() in any language. It's quite sexy.

Answer (score 0):

Why write x*(1000/4), if you can write x*250? I mean why give the runtime the additional headache of string parsing, splitting (and chance of errors due to missing commas, commas inside the strings etc..) etc? I don't see anything more than some weird coding convention in writing code that way.

Answer (score 0):

Easier to type because you have less quotes. Not suitable for something more complex than a list of words.